# How to get the actual IP address of the Cloud Flare proxy server that is being replaced by nginx with user's IP address

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, cloudflare, laravel-forge

My visitors IP address is being fed into my php application and replaced by the actual HTTP Header between the server and cloudflare using these nginx configuration:

```
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18; 
//....
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;

real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

And I can now access it via php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], however in my application I am in need of getting the cloudflare IP address. What can I add here so it passes the IP as another variable accessible via  $_SERVER.

I am having issues with Laravel Jetstreams built in URL signature verifications, and none of the plugins for TrustProxies middleware that handles cloudflare seems to work. I am trying to see the IP address of the cloudflare node to make sure it exists in my list of IP CIDR but can't figure out how to do that.